# Mongoid: how to store embedded objects in different container (like store_in)

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in :citizens
  embeds_many :presonal_addresses
end

class PersonalAddress
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeded_in :person
  store_in :addresses # but it seems not to work
end
```

I want class for embeded doc in rails to be called **PersonalAddress** but store it in attribute called **addresses**, not **personal_addresses**:

```
"citizens": {"_id": ..., "addresses": [{"_id":...},{..}]} but not:
citizens: {"_id": ..., "personal_addresses": [{"_id":...},{..}]}
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in :citizens
  embeds_many :addresses, :class_name => "PersonalAddress"
end

class PersonalAddress
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeded_in :person, :inverse_of => :addresses
end
```